# My UINavigationControllerDelegate got delloacted after app load main view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement custom animations for UINavigation controller.

I add some properties in Appdelegate:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
...
// for custrom navigation transition animation
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *AppNavigationController;
...
@end
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
self.AppNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)((REFrostedViewController *)self.window.rootViewController).contentViewController;
        MyNavigationControllerDelegate * naviDelegate = [[MyNavigationControllerDelegate alloc] init];
self.AppNavigationController.delegate = naviDelegate;
    }
...
}
```

While debugging, so far I can see the delegate:

```
(lldb) po self.AppNavigationController
<UINavigationController: 0x14f52bb90>

(lldb) po self.AppNavigationController.delegate
<MyNavigationControllerDelegate: 0x17424c5a0>
```

When my Main View Controller loads, I can still see

```
(lldb) po 0x14f52bb90
<UINavigationController: 0x14f52bb90>
```

But when tries to access 0x14f52bb90 its delegate,

```
(lldb) po [0x14f52bb90 delegate]
2015-02-28 18:54:14.724 MyApp[1995:489717] *** -[MyNavigationControllerDelegate respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17424c5a0
0x000000017424c5a0
```

I am not sure why the delegate got deallocated, and how to fix it. Any ideas?

MyNavigationControllerDelegate init code:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.pushAnimator = [[PushAnimator alloc] init];
        self.popAnimator = [[PopAnimator alloc] init];
        UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)app.delegate;
        self.navigationController = appDelegate.AppNavigationController;
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
        [self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and further crash trace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x778f5, 0x0000000184a72440 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x184a72440)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000184a72440 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 968
    frame #1: 0x0000000184976b6c CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    frame #2: 0x00000001892d1d4c UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 908
    frame #3: 0x00000001892d16dc UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 640
    frame #4: 0x00000001892d13fc UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
    frame #5: 0x00000001892d137c UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `delegate` property on your `AppNavigationController` is defined as `@property(assign)` (or without any modifiers which defaults to `assign`), thus when `-application:didFinishLoadingWithOptions` finishes, `delegate` is deallocated because it is not retained anywhere.

If that is the case, you can fix it with `@property(strong)`.

**Edit**

`UINavigationController` property `delegate` is defined as `assign`, so you need to retain delegate in some other place, I would suggest this:

MyAppDelegate

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
...
@property(strong) MyNavigationControllerDelegate* naviDelegate;   
...
@end
```

didFinishlaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...

self.AppNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)((REFrostedViewController *)self.window.rootViewController).contentViewController;
self.naviDelegate = [[MyNavigationControllerDelegate alloc] init];
self.AppNavigationController.delegate = self.naviDelegate;

...
}
```

Comment: But I am just use the UINavigationController's property delegate. I do not declare this property, but Apple does. Meanwhile, I take a look at other example, they don't have my issue while we share most of the code. I am confused why only my app got this bug.

Comment: I have edited my response. As I explained, you don't have the delegate retained - in that other example you've mentioned, they probably did have it retained somewhere.

Comment: thanks, I will dig more in this tomorrow, and come back

Comment: I ended up with your solutions while trying others. Seems like your way did solved the problem, but I am still looking for other reasons and better answers, like don't store the delegate globally.